# StaticLayout setMaxLines draws all lines no matter what's specified

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, staticlayout

I am trying to draw multiline text with StaticLayout but the `setMaxLines()` does not seem to work. This is my code:

```kotlin
val eventText = StaticLayout.Builder
    .obtain(event.title, 0, event.title.length, eventTextPaint, (contentWidth / 7f).toInt())
    .setMaxLines(2)
    .build()
withTranslation(event.left, event.top * scale) {
    eventText.draw(this)
}
```

But the all of the text is drawn which is 5 lines long. If I add `setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)` I get two lines which is specified in code but with "..." at end, which I do not want. What am I doing wrong? Or is the Builder broken?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting the maximum number a lines doesn't truncate the text within the *StaticLayout*, but specifies to other code, such as *TextView*, how many lines are to be displayed.

For example, using the following *TextView* definition

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="This is some long text that spans more than two lines. This is some long text that spans more than two lines. This is some long text that spans more than two lines"/>
```

and setting a breakpoint [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=8084?q=textview.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) in the *TextView* code we see the following at the breakpoint. In the `onDraw()` method of *TextView*, a clip rectangle is defined that has its bottom set to the bottom of line 1 (the second line). It is this code that restricts the number of lines to be displayed. The text in the layout is the long text but only two lines are displayed.

[image]

What is displayed:

[image]

You will need to do something similar to limit the number of lines displayed, or you can examine the *StaticLayout* and truncate the number of characters at the second line.